# Loop text to match character count between two linked list in C

Tags: c

I have this text that I want to loop to match the count of my elements in a linked list.

```
char myBaseArray[] = "close your eyes ";
```

I have this linked list made of int (0 and 1) like this :

```
linkedListOne = 1 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0
```

I want to make a second linked list with the same number of 0's and 1's and loop through my base array for text. In other words, 1's and 0's are letters but I want to keep the blanks with my base array.

Example 1 :

```
linkedListOne = 1 -> 0   (2 elements in my list)
linkedListTwo = c -> l   (2 letters)
```

Example 2 :

```
linkedListOne = 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 (20 elements in my list)
linkedListTwo = c -> l -> o -> s -> e ->(blank)-> y -> o -> u -> r ->(blank)-> e -> y -> e -> s ->(blank)->c -> l -> o -> s -> e->(blank)->y -> o(20 letters)
```

As you can see blank does not count as a 0 or 1.

The example 2 is more complex because I have to add blank spaces in my linked list so when I print it, it will output :

```
close your eyes close yo
```

Another output with a very long list could be :

```
close your eyes close your eyes close your eyes close your eyes close your eyes
```

My linked list are working just fine and I have implemented a count function so I know the numbers of 1's and 0's. I am not sure on how to loop through my base array to match that count.

Comment: It's not clear what the meaning of 1s and 0s is... and the output you show can be easily generated by indexing the array in a circular fashion a given amount of times...so what's the point of the linked lists?

Comment: The 1s and 0s are upper-case and lower case letter that I will later transform.

Comment: What is your question? And there *are* no uppercase letters in the examples each followed or preceded by a mix of 0s and 1s.

Comment: linkedListOne contains the capitalisation in "binary", so 11111 will be CLOSE. I am not sure how to capitalise or decapitalise the text yet so for now I just want to match the numbers of characters with the numbers of 0 and 1. I use linked list because the message is gonna repeat itselft a lot and its a variable lenght message so I cant use arrays, and its easier to add/remove something in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended doing this :

```
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while(i != LETTER_COUNT)
    {
        char c = myBaseArray[j % myBaseArray_LENGTH];
        if(c == ' '){
            linkedListTwo = add(linkedListTwo,  c);
            j++;
        }
        else{
            linkedListTwo= add(linkedListTwo,  c);
            j++;
            i++;    
    }
}
```